# What do the 6 different "Path" options do in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

In inkscape, on the "Path" drop down, there are (among others) 6 options:

- Union
- Difference
- Intersection
- Exclusion
- Division
- Cut path

What do each of these do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Union Option:

[image]

Here we see the 2 paths become 1. The colour is taken from whichever shape is on top.

## The Difference Option:

[image]

In this one, whichever image is on top has it's shape "removed" from the one below (like cookie dough cutter). The colour is taken from whichever shape is on the bottom.

## The Intersection Option:

[image]

The overlap is the only bit kept here. If there is no overlap, nothing will be left over. The colour is taken from whichever shape is on the bottom.

## The Exclusion Option:

[image]

In this one the overlap is removed, and the rest is kept. The colour is taken from whichever shape is on the bottom.

## The Division Option:

[image]

This is like using the Difference Option and the Intersection Option one after the other. It creates 2 shapes. The colour is taken from whichever shape is on the bottom.

## The Cut Paths Option:

[image]

This one is quite messed up. When I first did it, the results were completely transparent. However, on the left we have a whole square (no change) and on the right we have a circle cut into 2, like the Division option.

My pronouns are He / Him